# How to force the presentation of all y-axis value in R?

Tags: r

While plotting a boxplot in R, I noticed not all values in the y-axis are presented. Possible values are -5 to 5, but actual values are -1.3 to 4.6, so the values presented on the y-axis are -2 to 5. I want it to be presented with all values: -5 to 5, even though there's no data for this entire range.

My code looks like this:

`boxplot(depvar ~ indepvar, data = a, pars = list(outlwd = 2, outcex = 1.8), axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 2, at = seq(-5, 5, by = 1), las = 1, tck = 7)`

What should be added/changed for the y-axis to be fully-presented?

Comment: Hi Stars, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(a)` or if your data is very large `dput(a[1:20,])`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears simliar to this question: [How to set the y range in boxplot graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247907/how-to-set-the-y-range-in-boxplot-graph)

I think you are looking for ylim.

```
a <- c((randu$x*3)-2)

boxplot(x = a,
  ylim = c(-5,5))
```

[image]

Comment: That solved my problem. Can't believe I missed it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Load Packages

install.packages("dplyr")
 library(dplyr)

## creating random set with two columns:

```
set.seed(10)
 df <- dplyr::data_frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = 1:5)
```

> ## Visualize in a boxplot with expanded axis:

```
boxplot(x~y,
  df,
  xlim =c(-5,5),
  ylim =c(-5,5))
```